# Prove fundamental group of R/~ is isomorphic to Z

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-isomorphism, quotient-spaces, fundamental-groups, path-connected

I need help with this $$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}/\sim)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$$
I am not sure if this proposition is true or false.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}: f(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ and let $\sim$ the equivalence relation defined: $x\sim y\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$.
So I think that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}/\sim)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ is false but I don't know how to prove it.
I know that $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is path connected and also that $f$ is continous but I can't find a isomorphism or contradiction.

Comment: Why do you think it's false? Points are identified under your equivalence relation if and only if $x \equiv y \pmod{2\pi}$. So $S^1\cong \mathbb{R}/\sim$.

Comment: yes, I was thinking something like that but, what function could be a homeomorphism?

Comment: The map $f$ induces the homeomorphism (note that it takes values in $S^1\subseteq\mathbb{C})$.